# What are the security concerns of Jenkins Windows Service/DCOM control of slaves?

Tags: jenkins

Setting up some new Jenkins boxes on Azure and I'm wondering what the security implications are of opening up all the required ports on my master & slave machines:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Windows+slaves+fail+to+start+via+DCOM

Is this opening up my servers to significantly more risk having these additional ports opened?

Comment: Does connecting to slaves via ssh help? You will need a ssh server running in windows though.

Comment: One of the common security problems with Jenkins is that it's not locked down by default. Enable security (which of course makes it trickier to configure slaves) and your setup should be no less secure compared to other multi-tier applications. I endorse @NotAgain recommendation of using SSH. Certificate based authentication is always preferable.

Comment: Any good references for getting SSH set up on Jenkins (Windows)?

Comment: The easy and open source way out will be to install a bare bone cygwin and install openssh on it and run it. 
Other option will be to look as WinScp based solution. IIRC it is also opensource. 
I will suggest you explore this option too: 
Launch slave agents via Java Web Start
Jenkins then gives you a slave.jar which you can download on the slave. Then just open a command window on slave and execute the command Jenkins gives to connect the slave to the Master.